# Sidenav (Menu / Submenu) Angular 4 Material Design 2

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I'm working in a project with Angular 4 and Material Design (Angular Material). I have trouble with the sidenav menu. I don't know how to create a sub menu or subcategories. I need to add (Maths, Communication, Arts) below of each disability.

Categories:

[image: Categories]

This is my code:

```
  <md-list-item>
    <md-icon md-list-icon>face</md-icon>
    <span class="sidenav-item-name" md-line>{{category.name}}</span>
    <md-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</md-icon>
   </md-list-item>
```

I found an example of the menu but it didn't work:

```
<a> 
 <md-icon aria-hidden="true">trending_flat</md-icon> 
 <span>Menu</span> <md-icon aria-hidden="true">chevron_right</md-icon> 
</a> 
<md-nav-list> 
 <md-list-item routerlinkactive="open"> 
  <div > <a routerlinkactive="active-link" href="/pages/blank">Sub Menu1</a> 
  </div> 
 </md-list-item> 
 <md-list-item routerlinkactive="open"> 
  <div > <a routerlinkactive="active-link" href="/pages/blank">Sub Menu2</a> 
  </div> 
 </md-list-item> 
</md-nav-list>
```

I don't know how to implement it right or what extra code or "class" I need to add. This is how it looks.

Menu with error:

[image: Menu with error]

Comment: Show some code plz thst you have tried so far

Comment: You say it didn't work can you please be more specific